# Why the inner array typescript is not accessible in Angular 5 app?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, jax-rs

I have the following JSON definitions:

```
 export class Company {
      name: string;
      trips : Trip[] = [];
    }

export class Trip{
    id: number;
    name: string;        
}
```

In the component I have a method which include the following:

```
const children = this.company.trips;
console.log(children.length);
```

The console show "undefined" for the length which means that it is not an array.

This is part of the "company" object from the java code:

```
@XmlElement(name = "trip")
private Set<Trip> trips = new HashSet<Trip>(0);
```

This is part of the "company" object from the console:

```
{id: 1, user: {...},{...}
country: {code:"UK", id: 229}
trip: {id: 1, name: "ABC"}
```

I've tried also to add @XmlElementWrapper:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="trips")
@XmlElement(name = "trip")
private Set<Trip> trips = new HashSet<Trip>(0);
```

In this case I'm getting the following response:

```
"trips":{"trip":{"id":1,"name":"ABC"}}}}
```

I need an array/list and to access the value through a loop, can someone help
me with this please?
Should I change something in Java side?

Thanks.

Comment: try with const children = this.company.trip;
console.log(children.length);

Comment: as @Sajeetharan said, your Java API seams to returns `trip` rather than `trips`. You might want to change the definition in your `Company` class.

Comment: I've changed the java to trips and still the length is undefined.

Comment: Well, clearly the returned JSON does not contain an array, as you can tell by the missing square brackets. If trips needs to be an array, your problem is on the Java side ...

Comment: In the java side it is a Set and the value are generated to the angular app, I need a solution and yes if I need to change something in the java I will.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response you've posted it should be as trip not as trips, change the definition as follows,

```
export class Company {
      name: string;
      trip : Trip[] = [];
    }

export class Trip{
    id: number;
    name: string;        
}
```

and this should work,

```
const children = this.company.trip;
console.log(children.length);
```

Comment: The way that is work is trip : {} trip {} trip {} in case there are 3 trips for example.

Comment: Do you have Idea what should I change

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using list instead of array, the Json presentation is a list
and not array as it doesn't include the the bracket ("[]").

```
const children = this.company.trips;
 for(let property of Object.values(children)){
      console.log(property.name);
  }
```